# udots in TikzPic problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I'm having a problem making a diagram in tikzpicture. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[.3]{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
The wedge $W = A_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge A_n$ is a pushout in the category  of topological spaces, $\textbf{Top}$.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
\node (one) at (0,2) {\textbf{1}};
\node (A1) at (2, 2) {$A_1$};
\node (An) at (0, 0) {$A_n$};
\node (W) at (2, 0) {$W$};
\node (dots) at (1,1) {$\udots$};
\draw[->] (one) to node {}(A1);
\draw[->] (one) to node {}(An);
\draw[->] (An) to node {}(W);
\draw[->] (A1) to node {} (W);
\node[->] (one) to node {} (dots);
\node[->] (dots) to node {} (W);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And the output lacks the two last arrows. The error message is from tikz and says "A node must have a (possibly empty) label text." The problems only started when I tried to add the dots in there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, better suggestions for the diagram would also be welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the last two commands be `\draw` rather than `\node`? Also, all of the `node {}` seem unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Don't load `MnSymbol` just for `\udots`; the symbol can be defined in a different way. For the diagram there's `tikz-cd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\providecommand{\udots}{\Udots}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Udots}{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
    \halign{%
      \hbox to .8em{##}\cr
      \hfil.\cr\noalign{\kern.2ex}
      \hfil.\hfil\cr\noalign{\kern.2ex}
      .\hfil\cr}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The wedge $W = A_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge A_n$ is a pushout in the
category of topological spaces, $\textbf{Top}$
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1em,column sep=1em]
\textbf{1} \arrow{rr} \arrow{dd} \arrow{dr} && A_1 \arrow{dd} \\
& \udots \arrow{dr} \\
A_n \arrow{rr} && W
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]